# Symfony 4 occasionally Compile Error: require(): Failed opening required

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4

On occasion in production and not reproducible locally we get these kind of exceptions:

**getDoctrine_Orm_DefaultListeners_AttachEntityListenersService**:

```
{
    "class": "Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\Exception\\FatalErrorException",
    "message": "Compile Error: require(): Failed opening required '\/srv\/api\/var\/cache\/prod\/ContainerWKxhZGH\/getDoctrine_Orm_DefaultListeners_AttachEntityListenersService.php' (include_path='.:\/usr\/local\/lib\/php')",
    "code": 0,
    "file": "\/srv\/api\/var\/cache\/prod\/ContainerWKxhZGH\/srcApp_KernelProdContainer.php:532"
}
```

**getSession_Storage_NativeService**:

```
{
    "class": "Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\Exception\\FatalErrorException",
    "message": "Compile Error: require(): Failed opening required '\/srv\/api\/var\/cache\/prod\/ContainerAPB4itV\/getSession_Storage_NativeService.php' (include_path='.:\/usr\/local\/lib\/php')",
    "code": 0,
    "file": "\/srv\/api\/var\/cache\/prod\/ContainerAPB4itV\/srcApp_KernelProdContainer.php:532"
}
```

**getApiPlatform_Listener_View_RespondService**:

```
{
    "class": "Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\Exception\\FatalErrorException",
    "message": "Compile Error: require(): Failed opening required '\/srv\/api\/var\/cache\/prod\/Container8GRzllw\/getApiPlatform_Listener_View_RespondService.php' (include_path='.:\/usr\/local\/lib\/php')",
    "code": 0,
    "file": "\/srv\/api\/var\/cache\/prod\/Container8GRzllw\/srcApp_KernelProdContainer.php:532"
}
```

We have two instances running and use Symfony as API. We clear the cache when booting which nowadays also warms it up.

Symfony v4.3.4

Anyone got an idea where to start looking for the issue?

Comment: i feel like cache:clear and cache:warmup do their respective warming up differently. I can't really tell so far, where the difference is though. but did you try just warming up the cache explicitly, just to see if the same errors appear?

Comment: Same issue if I clear and warmup the cache manually.

Comment: so .. is there any code in your project that might clear parts of the cache? are multiple servers using the same directory?

Comment: The issue was caused by a wrongly configured Kubernetes readinessProbe which resulted in the cache being cleared and warmed up again, hence the missing references sometimes.